# Knockout.js: clear selection in select element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I need to clear the selection from a `<select>` element. ***I've already read such posts as [Knockoutjs clear selected value in combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137222/knockoutjs-clear-selected-value-in-combobox) and have tried the accepted answers, but those solutions don't seem to be working*** (don't know if something has changed in Knockout 2 since the answer was accepted?).

Here's an example view model:

```
var ClearSelectionViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.station = ko.observable();

    self.selectedStation = ko.observable();
    self.selectedStation.subscribe(function (value) {
        self.station(value);
    });

    self.stations = ko.observableArray(['CLT', 'PHL', 'PHX', 'PIT']);

    self.clearSelectedStation = function () {
        self.selectedStation(null);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClearSelectionViewModel());​
```

When the `clearSelectedStation` is invoked, the bound view model property should be set to `null` and this should be reflected in the UI by the bound `<select>` element appearing blank and expanding the list of options revealing no highlighted items. However, what I'm noticing is that if you try to set the bound value property (`selectedStation`) to anything not in the array of options (`stations`), the binding seems to be ignored.

This fiddle illustrates what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/sellmeadog/Su8Zq/1/

I don't want to "pollute" the options array with a blank value if I don't have to. I would like to know how to get the solution in the linked post to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to use the `optionsCaption` additional binding for the "not selected" value.  It has to be set to something for it to be used, but you could set it to `" "`.

```
<select data-bind="optionsCaption: ' ', options: stations, value: selectedStation"></select>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Su8Zq/3/

Comment: it can also be empty string, doesn't have to contain space; this might not be important for your case, but Select2 replaces empty option with its own placeholder, which it can't do if it contains a space

Answer (score 2):

Just add an 'optionsCaption', like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: stations, value: selectedStation, optionsCaption: '-- SELECT --'"></select>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Su8Zq/2/