# Impossible to reset Chosen value with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-chosen

When selecting values on chosen lists on a page, then leaving the page, then coming back, the values are still set in the chosen selects. No matter what I do.

I've already searched a lot for this. I've tried the following:

```
$(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
$(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

I've tried to add optionsCaption in data-bind, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300258/knockout-js-clear-selection-in-select-element).

I am desperately resetting my value observables to null, '', [], whatever, nothing works.

Any super trick here?

Thanks

Update: here's code, if that can help.
Html:

```
<select class="chzn-select left" multiple id="selectsector" data-bind="optionsCaption: '', options: sectors(), selectedOptions: selectedSectors, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

And JS:

```
var sectors = ko.observableArray(),
    selectedSectors = ko.observableArray();
```

I populate sectors with standard js objects, nothing fancy and it works well.

Nicolas

Comment: jsFiddle or source code of your custom binding will help to understand the problem better.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how a fiddle can help since the problem happens when I leave page and come back. But I'll paste source code in updated question.

Comment: Well you may have to simulate the issue differently in jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the observable's value to null inside of your view model -

```
selectedSectors([]);
```

You cannot use jQuery to clear a Knockout observable's value.

Answer (score -1):

I had a case where my observable was one way by design. Setting the observable to null did not work. To reset it, I used

`selectedSelectors(undefined);`

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. How is this unhelpful? I was looking for a solution, and found this post. Others will find it, and see my solution. Maybe it will help them.