# knockout.js - setting an empty selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout.js to populate and manage a `<select/>` box.  I'd like the initial value to be empty.

However, I'm having trouble trying to force the managed value to be null at any time, let alone initially.

For example, consider [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjVBN/1/):

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: myOptions, value: myValue"></select> aka
<span data-bind="text: myValue"></span>

<div>
    <button data-bind="click: setMyValue(null)">clear the selection</button>
    <button data-bind="click: setMyValue('one')">select "one"</button>
    <button data-bind="click: setMyValue('four')">select "four"</button>
</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: log">
    <li>message: <span data-bind="text: message"></span></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function Model() {
    var self = this;
    self.myOptions = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
    self.myValue = ko.observable();
    self.setMyValue = function (val) {
        return function(){
            this.log.push({
                message: "ok, trying to set value as " + val
            });
            self.myValue(val);
        };
    };
    self.log = ko.observableArray([]);
}
var model = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The `select "one"` and `select "four"` buttons work to change the selection by forcing an update of `myValue()`.  However, the clear the selection button doesn't work.  The selection is not cleared by `myValue(null)`, [which is what I thought was the proper way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137222/knockoutjs-clear-selected-value-in-combobox).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need the [optionsCaption](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters) binding set.

```
<select data-bind="options: myOptions, value: myValue, optionsCaption: 'select...'"></select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjVBN/2/)